SignalR : Server closed with an error message issue while image processing
While sending base64 or byte[] value the invoke send message method in signalR, the server closes with the following error message:
   document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("username").textContent;
    var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    var fileInput = document.getElementById("file").value;

    var fileParam = fileInput ? fileInput : null;

    if (message || fileParam) {

                connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message, fileParam ).catch(function (err) {
                    console.error(err.toString());
                });
        }
        
        document.getElementById("messageInput").value = "";
        fileInput.value = ""; // Clear the file input
    }

document.getElementById("attachments").addEventListener("change", function (event) {
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var base64String = e.target.result.split(",")[1];
        document.getElementById("file").value = base64String;
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
readAsDataURL
});


This is my Hub

    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;namespace SignalRChat.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message,string file)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message,file);
        }
    }
}

I tried with different format of datatype for the processing. I'm expecting the invoke method to successfully accept the base64 format.

"server closes with the following error message", you didn't include the error message. Also, it's useful to show what the hub method(s) look like.

That is the only error message i got on my console
